# How to change column entries in Q/KDB

Tags: string, kdb

I have a table named Pnl having many columns, one of them is Tenor with following entries:

```
**Tenor**

5y

10y

20y

10Y

5Y

25Y

20y
```

How can I modify these rows in q/kdb such that 'y' & 'Y' become similar? 
I tried converting atoms into strings using `string`Tenor but it doesn't work for a column.

Answer (score 2):

You can use upper (or lower) to make the entries consistent:

```
update upper Tenor from tbl
```

Answer (score -1):

sol1: update {ssr[string[x];"y";"Y"]} each tenor from table
sol2: update {(-1_string[x]),"Y"} each tenor from t

Comment: can avoid using the lambdas
update ssr[;"y";"Y"] each string tenor from table
update (-1_'string tenor),\:"Y" from table
but in either case it makes more sense yo use the upper or lower operator